# Windows stops booting while EXE in runonce is active

Tags: windows-7, registry, runonce

I have written an MFC app (executable) that performs some tasks, and which is started via "Runonce" in Windows 7 registry.

My problem is that windows, or especially windows explorer does not boot until I quit that exe. How can I make my EXE run asynchronously, so that it can perform tasks, but Windows will continue booting? Is there some basic thing I am missing here?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It maybe such an issue if you put your application into

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

As it said on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365/en-us

> Entries in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\RunOnce key are loaded synchronously in an undefined order.
>
> Because the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\RunOnce key is loaded synchronously, all of its entries must finish loading before the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\Run, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\Run, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\RunOnce, and Startup Folder entries can be loaded.

Suitable workaround for this situation maybe adding something like this as registry value in HKLM\...\RunOnce

```
cmd /c "start "myAppTitle" "path to myMegaApp.exe" "params""
```

It is can be successfully used to bypass UAC promt (make sure that you writing registry key as admin and login after reboot as user of admin group).

Another way

- put your app to HKCU\...\RunOnce (which entries load asynchronously)(if you don't need admin rights for your application)
- use Task Scheduler API which provides a lot of interesting stuff